# Call Future method inside Future method in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have two future functions that does not have any kind of errors. additionally these functions are asynchronous functions. but when I try to call `fetchStoryData` from inside `getRecentProgress`, it is not calling...

```
Future<dynamic> getRecentProgress(story) async {
    DocumentSnapshot df = await user.doc(globals.user.uid).get();
    var recentStory;
    if( ((df.data() as Map)[story]) == null) {
      print("_-_-_-_-_-_ NO RECENT STORY _-_-_-_-_-_-_");
    } else {
      recentStory = ((df.data()) as Map)[story];
      print("_-_-_-_-_-_ RECENT STORY _-_-_-_-_-_-_\n$recentStory");
    }
    var storyData = await fetchStoryData(recentStory, story);
    print("_-_-_-_-_-_ FETCH STORY DATA _-_-_-_-_-_\n$storyData");
    return storyData;
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchStoryData(List<dynamic> storytList, story) async {

    print("_-_-_-_-_-_ FUNCTION CALL _-_-_-_-_-_");

    Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = {};
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await stories.doc(story).get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        for (var fieldName in storytList) {
          dataMap[fieldName] = (snapshot.data() as Map)[fieldName];
          print("_-_-_-_-_-_ DATA _-_-_-_-_-_$dataMap");
        }
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print("Error fetching story data: $e");
    }

    return dataMap;
  }
```

Comment: what do you see if you run `final progress = await getRecentProgress(...); print(progress)`?

Comment: what prints do you actually get?

Comment: "there are no apparent errors in the functions". I spot one already. if it comes in the `NO RECENT STORY` part `recentStory` will be `null` and then `fetchStoryData` gets called with `null` as first parameter which is not allowed and will throw an exception. Also it's not apparant that even in the `RECENT STORY` case that `recentStory` will be a `List`. Whenever you are dealing with dynamic variables you better make sure you are dealing with the right types. Even better if you can rewrite it to not use dynamic variables at all

Comment: @pskink 
```I/flutter (15748): _-_-_-_-_-_ RECENT STORY _-_-_-_-_-_-_
I/flutter (15748): story_initial_episode```

this is what I see when I run getRecentProgress.

Comment: @Ivo Yes, this could be alternative case if there is no data. But I know there is a data in document so ```recentStory``` holds ```story_initial_episode```

Comment: @pskink I mean that if I call ```fetchStoryData``` method from inside ```getRecentProgress``` atleast it should print ```_-_-_-_-_-_ FUNCTION CALL _-_-_-_-_-_``` in debug console but it isn't.

Comment: @pskink Yes, if it is written in ```getRecentProgress```

Comment: @pskink @Ivo Thanks for the help. issue is resolved, the problem is type of ```recentStory``` variable since it is declared with var it allows any type of value to be store so it is storing string type value but when calling ```fetchStoryData``` function I passed it as a List type. that is got mismatch and function won't call.